What would the critical path be for this circuit?
I have the following circuit for which I need the critical path:

For Path 1:

This has the maximum number of stages
Logical effort (NAND3) = 5/3. Total parasitic effort for this stage (excluding final gate) = 1 + 3 = 4

For Path 2:

1 less gate, but the gate is bigger. (NAND4)
Logical effort = 6/3, P = 4.

How would I decide on the critical path? Is it simply path 1 because I have more stages?
x1 = 3C. The first gate in path 1 is a regular unit CMOS inverter.
